# file download dialog in firefox via webdriver using python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I need to download pdf, text, csv files etc

I got the code

```
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile','text/plain')
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain')

    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile',"application/pdf")
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
```

It works individually. Can anyone let me know the syntax for combining all the options?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get rid of the redundant code pattern then you could use list comprehension in the following manner:

```
[profile.set_preference(*opt) for opt in [('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile','text/plain'),
                                          ('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain'),
                                          ('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile',"application/pdf"),
                                          ('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf'),
                      # (more options)
                      ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below solution

Separate them with a comma and it worked:

setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,text/plain");